# Save text without button by Shared Preserence

Tags: android

I had built a mobile app which consists of 2 activity as shown in the figure below. It can let the user choose for go to main activity or the second activity

Main activity let user to send text to the second activity.
Second Activity let user to recieve text from main activity.

Can somebody teach me how I can save the text received in the second activity by using shared preference directly. That mean everytime second activity recieved text, it can save the text itself and user don't need to press an save button manually for saving that text

Below shown the layout of my app and code for that 2 activity

[image: App layout]

[image: MainActivity_Layout]

[image: SecondActivity_Layout]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText SendValue;
Button SendEditTextValue;
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SendEditTextValue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SendValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SendEditTextValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", SendValue.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView receive;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        receive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        receive.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of set text you can take it in one variable and then set in textview as well as save in preference.

Comment: @Lemon_Foam please check.. have updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in second activity`onCreate`

```
    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
   {
     if (! getIntent()
    getStringExtraa("EdiTtEXTvALUE").isEmpty())
     {
    this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    .putString("EdiTtEXTvALUE",getIntent()
    getStringExtraa("EdiTtEXTvALUE")).apply();
     }
   }
  if ( ! this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("EdiTtEXTvALUE","").isEmpty()) 
    { 
         receive.setText(this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("EdiTtEXTvALUE","");
    }
```

Comment: i had updated my code in second activity, but it still not working as i desred, my updated code is in below

Comment: how do you know its not working ?? and please edit you question dont put it as answer.. @Lemon_Foam

Comment: @Lemon_Foam do you wanna save the text in the first activity ?? or do you wanna save the text in the 2nd activity ..?? and what is the output you want but not getting ??

Comment: Actually the MainActivity only use to send text and i want to use SecondActivity to display and save it, so that every time when click to go into secondActivity, it display the last text recieved from MainActivity

Comment: How do you know the text is saved or not ? @Lemon_Foam its already saved..you can get it from any other activity ... now..

Comment: Below shown my code, is it correct? Because it still cannot save text in Secondactivity

Comment: yes it is correct because  in your second activity after the text is displayed...the **text is saved** in your shared preferences... @Lemon_Foam

Comment: @Lemon_Foam did you get what i am saying ??

Comment: But sir, when i quit the app and run the app again, i click the button to go into the secondactivity, there have no anything display

Comment: you have to show from the shared prefs ..i am updating the code please check.. @Lemon_Foam

Comment: Sir there is still a problem, after i updated my code, and install it in my phone, when i click to go into Mainactivity, my app work normally , but when  i click to go into  Secondactivity, my app is kept stopping

Comment: first enter a text in the edittext and then 2nd time close tge app and check.. @Lemon_Foam

Comment: ya, i use the code provided by sir the latest version of Secondactivity code is shown below

Comment: But every time i want to click to go into Secondactivity to see whether anything had been saved, my app forced to stop itself

Comment: post your code of second Activity please .. @Lemon_Foam

Comment: My editted code is shown below, u can have a check sir

Comment: yes its fine post your crash log..please @Lemon_Foam

Comment: Sir, u menant event Log ?

Comment: there i a log cat window..which displays the crashes ..post that please

Comment: i have updated the code please check the latest code @Lemon_Foam

Comment: Sir, still not working, Secondactivity still forced to stop

Comment: i updated the latest editted code already, there is no error, but still the same, second activity forced to stop itself.

Comment: happy to help :) actually i am not in pc(using mobile) so it took so long @Lemon_Foam

Comment: It is ok, i have search on internet to find a suitable solution for the whole day already, finally u help me to solve my problem, really need to thx to sir,

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

TextView receive;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    receive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    receive.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE"));



    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
    {
        if (! getIntent()
        .getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE").isEmpty())
        {
            this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    .putString("EdiTtEXTvALUE",getIntent()
                            .getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE")).apply();
        }
    }
    if ( ! this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("EdiTtEXTvALUE","").isEmpty())
    {
        receive.setText(this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefName",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("EdiTtEXTvALUE",""));
    }
```

}